# Why does my iPhone 7 have a laser?

Tags: hardware, iphone

In the box of my iPhone 7 there was a leaflet with all sorts of small print easy enough to be dismissed as some legal document (and maybe it is). I couldn't help reading it and on the reverse page it says something about *Class 1 Laser Information*:
[image: Class 1 Laser Product Information from iPhone Box Leaflet]
See text: "This device contains a laser"

So my question is where in the iPhone and, more importantly, for what purpose is the laser in the iPhone?

Comment: Just curious (and if permissible here): Hands up who never knew there was a laser on an iPhone! ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[This site](http://www.systemplus.fr/reverse-costing-reports/stmicroelectronics-time-of-flight-proximity-sensor-in-the-apple-iphone-7-plus/) indicates that the front facing proximity sensor consists of the laser and filters to attenuate the signal to safe levels once assembled.

> Located in the front of the phone, above the main speaker, the FlightSenseTM proximity sensor uses optical land-grid array (LGA) packaging. The custom Apple device measures 2.80 mm x 2.40 mm, half the size of the rest of STMicroelectronics’s portfolio.

That reinforces the warning about repair and implies potential danger if you operate the components while the iPhone is disassembled.

Comment: it's also possible the camera may use a laser focus, not sure on that though

Comment: Thanks. This article only mentions the iPhone 7 Plus, not the iPhone 7, but maybe they only examined the 7 Plus. // With the rumour of 3D capabilities of the next iPhone, I wonder if there will be another laser for that. The article you quote mentions something about that.